# Compare and keep items that are in Multiple Laravel Collections

Tags: laravel, collections

I have multiple Laravel collections that I want to compare. I know of the merge, intersect and diff methods, but I want to only keep the items that are found in all of the collections. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained in [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-intersect) and as you mentioned above. The best option is to use the intersect method which keeps only the values that are present in the given array or collection.